# How to use compiled resource file with SDL_LoadBMP

Tags: c++, windows, resources, bitmap, sdl

I have to use NetBeans 7.1.1 for C++ in Windows 7 and I am writing an application using SDL. I can get SDL_LoadBMP to work fine with an external file but I want my resources to be compiled as part of the EXE.

I found out you can build RES files to link to the EXE so I tried modifying my build script by adding:

```
.build-pre:
    windres player.res player.o
```

Then in the linker settings for the project I added player.o to the libraries. This compiles just fine but now I can't figure out how to refer to this .o file. I've tried using FindResource() and LoadResource() and they always give me NULL. I have included a header file that has #define PLAYER_IMAGE 1000. The code looks like this:

```
HRSRC res = FindResource(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(PLAYER_IMAGE), RT_BITMAP);

if(!res) {
    fprintf(stderr, "The resource couldn't be found.\n");
}

HGLOBAL res_handle = LoadResource(NULL, res);
if(!res_handle) {
    fprintf(stderr, "The resource couldn't be loaded.\n");
}

char* res_data = (char*)LockResource(res_handle);
```

Am I on the right track? If so, what am I doing wrong? If not what should I do instead?

Comment: Have you checked the return value of MAKEINTRESOURCE(PLAYER_IMAGE)? It should be a LPTSTR representing the name of the resource.

Comment: MAKEINTRESOURCE(PLAYER_IMAGE) returns 1000, which is the value I have a #define for in my header.

Answer (score 0):

windres is for compiling .rc files into .res files, you then have to link the .res and .o files together with ld. Anyway yes, you're in the right tracks, you just have to use SDL_RWFromConstMem() to get the data from the resource.